# Numpy equal dtype

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

Should the keyword argument `dtype` is not considered in `np.equal`?

In the function [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html), it seems to indicate that `dtype` should a valid keyword argument, and I couldn't find anything saying that it will be ignored, but when using logical ufuncs, it does not seem to be used:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.14.2'
>>> a = b = np.arange(2).astype(np.uint8)
>>> np.equal(a, b, dtype=float).dtype
dtype('bool')
>>> np.add(a, b).dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> np.add(a, b, dtype=float).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I would expect any ufunc to have the same output type if the return dtype is specified, but `np.add` behaves as I expected, while `np.equal` does not. Is this behavior intended?

Comment: np.equal returns .... Output array of bools, or a single bool if x1 and x2 are scalars. Adding is different

Comment: So that takes precedence over specifying the output dtype?

Comment: np.equal(5, 5, dtype=float) => True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.equal()` is a "[ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html)", all of which have an optional `dtype` parameter.  But not all ufuncs actually need the `dtype` parameter--it's just part of their universal signature.

It is very uncommon to want to change the output dtype of `np.equal()`, but if you must, you can do this:

```
result = np.empty(np.broadcast(a, b).shape, float)
np.equal(a, b, out=result)
```

The `out` parameter makes `dtype` irrelevant (for all ufuncs), and you end up with 0.0 and 1.0 values in `result`.

Comment: Is this behavior documented anywhere? In the ufunc documentation, under the keyword argument it says "Overrides the dtype of the calculation and output arrays. Similar to signature," which seems to indicate `dtype` should be used.

Comment: @cnapun: The docs say *"Sometimes you may have an array of a certain data type and wish to add up all of its elements, but the result does not fit into the data type of the array."* - so the stated purpose of the `dtype` parameter is irrelevant for `equal()` because there is no way the result doesn't fit into `bool`.  You can read between the lines to understand why `dtype` does nothing for `equal()`.  Of course, if you strongly believe it should do something, you could submit a pull request for NumPy to enhance it.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing that out; it makes this make more sense. .